# How to pack images in Qt resource to be accessible from a static HTML resource

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-resource

I have a Qt Widgets project that employs QWebEngineView to show a static HTML page. That page will show an image that needs to be "packed" with the Qt executable/installer. Can I use the QRC file to add an image and refer to it from the HTML file?

I (pathetically) tried to access the image using the "qrc:/image..." notation, but I understand perfectly that the QWebEngineView shows an embedded browser that have no relation to the project's resources. An alternative way?

Comment: Not exactly understand what you want, but can you load the image to temporary file and to point it as a source in HTML?

Comment: could be a good solution as well. Only that in this case I need to deploy the html + picture to some temporary location. Like lesyk's answer

Comment: You can use `QTemporaryFile`, `QTemporaryDir` or `QDesktopServices::TempLocation` as utility for temporary location generation. One more way is to embed the image into HTML using Base64 encoding but it can make your HTMLs large and I am not sure that `QWebEngineView` supports it.

Answer (score 2):

For Qt 5.6 in main.cpp:

```
...
QString helpHTMLFile = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::TempLocation);
helpHTMLFile.append(QDir::separator());
helpHTMLFile.append("index.html");
QFile(helpHTMLFile).remove();
QFile(":/index.html").copy(helpHTMLFile);

QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("pathToFile", "file:///"+helpHTMLFile);

QString logo = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::TempLocation);
logo.append(QDir::separator());
logo.append("logo.svg");
QFile(logo).remove();
QFile(":/logo.svg").copy(logo);
...
```

In html:

```
...
<img src="logo.svg" class="loginFooterImg">
...
```

Comment: Looks like what I'm trying to do. Will check and return with results

Comment: Other option is to load images from web. (I am sure you thought about that.)

Comment: Not the case ... since this is just a simple desktop app